# Listar nomes numa query e enviar para uma ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Queria listar os nomes pertencentes a um grupo e enviar para uma ViewModel e serem recolhidos por uma View(detalhes).
Problema:

> 'IQueryable' does not contain a definition for
>   'NomeCatequizando' and no extension method 'NomeCatequizando'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable' could
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Controlador:

```
 public ActionResult Detalhes(int? id)
        {
            var grupo = db.Grupo.Where(g => g.GrupoID ==id).FirstOrDefault();

            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            //query para recolher as nomes dos catequizandos pertencentes ao grupo selecionado
            var queryNomeCatequizandos = (from g in db.Grupo
                                          join i in db.Inscricao on g.GrupoID equals i.GrupoID
                                          join c in db.Catequizando on i.CatequizandoID equals c.CatequizandoID
                                          join p in db.Pessoa on c.CatequizandoID equals p.PessoaID
                                          where g.GrupoID == i.GrupoID && i.CatequizandoID == c.CatequizandoID && c.CatequizandoID == p.PessoaID && g.GrupoID == id
                                          select new GrupoViewModel
                                          {
                                              NomeCatequizando = p.Nome,                                                                                  
                                          });



            if (queryNomeCatequizandos == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            GrupoViewModel model = new GrupoViewModel()
            {
                GrupoID = grupo.GrupoID,
                NomeCatequizando = queryNomeCatequizandos.NomeCatequizando,
            };


            return View(grupo);
        }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class GrupoViewModel
    {
        public int GrupoID { get; set; }
        public String AnoPastoral { get; set; }
        public String HoraInicio { get; set; }
        public String DiaSessao { get; set; }
        public String AnoCatequese { get; set; }
        public String LetraGrupo { get; set; }
        public String Sala { get; set; }
        public String Observacoes { get; set; }
        public String NomeCatequizando { get; set; }

    }
```

---

Tem um problema:
Model inscrição

> public int? GrupoID { get; set; }

Erro no controlador:

```
GrupoID = i.GrupoID,
```

Erro:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não está correta sua abordagem. O certo seria:

```
var queryNomeCatequizandos = (from g in db.Grupo
                              join i in db.Inscricao on g.GrupoID equals i.GrupoID
                              join c in db.Catequizando on i.CatequizandoID equals c.CatequizandoID
                              join p in db.Pessoa on c.CatequizandoID equals p.PessoaID
                              where g.GrupoID == i.GrupoID && i.CatequizandoID == c.CatequizandoID && c.CatequizandoID == p.PessoaID && g.GrupoID == id
                              select new GrupoViewModel
                              {
                                  GrupoID = i.GrupoID,
                                  NomeCatequizando = p.Nome
                              });
```

O `return` seria:

```
return View(queryNomeCatequizandos.ToList());
```

Isto aqui você pode remover:

```
        GrupoViewModel model = new GrupoViewModel()
        {
            GrupoID = grupo.GrupoID,
            NomeCatequizando = queryNomeCatequizandos.NomeCatequizando,
        };
```

A *View* teria algo como:

```
@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.ViewModels.GrupoViewModel>
```

E a listagem:

```
@foreach (var grupo in Model) { ... }
```

---

Pro problema do grupo nulo, faça o seguinte:

```
var queryNomeCatequizandos = (from g in db.Grupo
                              join i in db.Inscricao on g.GrupoID equals i.GrupoID
                              join c in db.Catequizando on i.CatequizandoID equals c.CatequizandoID
                              join p in db.Pessoa on c.CatequizandoID equals p.PessoaID
                              where g.GrupoID == i.GrupoID && i.CatequizandoID == c.CatequizandoID && c.CatequizandoID == p.PessoaID && g.GrupoID == id
                              select new GrupoViewModel
                              {
                                  GrupoID = i.GrupoID ?? 0,
                                  NomeCatequizando = p.Nome
                              });
```

Comment: Tem um problema o grupo não é obrigatoria.

Comment: Devia ter colocado isso na pergunta. Se não é obrigatório, como vai fazer pra selecionar pela sentença que você colocou?

Comment: Sou português e não percebi a contexto na palavra "sentença", mas uma Inscrição pode ou não estar relacionado a um grupo. ou seja, a ForeignKey pode ser null.

Comment: "Sentença" em português do Brasil é a query Linq. De qualquer forma, coloquei um melhoramento na resposta.

Comment: Surgiu outro problema na minha View, queria enviar mais informação para a View, sem ser a lista de Nomes, como por exemplo a "Letragrupo" , "sala", etc, que não é do tipo IEnumerable. Como posso resolver este problema?

Comment: Preenchendo mais coisas no *ViewModel* e agrupando em *View*. Abra outra pergunta, por favor.